# Crashes after rendering with Compositor Node connected

Tags: compositing-nodes

[image]

When I composite an image in blender and am planing out how I want it to look I look at it with the Viewer node and Blender kind of runs fine (lags a bit) but it works. When I connect all those nodes to the composite node and hit Render, Blender crashes.

Is there any tips to prevent this?

Comment: It shouldn't crash of course, but it may help to see the result if pressing *Use Nodes* button in the bottom of the Node Editor (and optionally *Backdrop*).

Comment: If blender is crashing, then that sounds like a bug which should be reported to the tracker. See [this guide](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1378/599) on how to write a useful bug report.

Comment: ya that was checked when i hit render. just not when i took the screenshot. i think the resolution of the video was just too much for blender to render with on my computer. i turned down the resolution percentage and it rendered. thanks for answering though.